# Aspose.Word alternatives

Tags: ms-word

Does anyone know of a good Aspose.Word alternative (or similar) product?
Can you mention any pro/con for using either?

I am currently evaluating Aspose.Word, and although it works like a charm, it's missing some of the functionalities that I require.

UPDATE: We ended up writing our own DOCX generator. We are still using Aspose.Word to convert to DOC/HTML when needed.

Comment: If you have `docx` you can use [Open XML SDK](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK) to convert to HTML for free. Aspose.Word is very expensive for what you get.

Comment: To be fair, here is an article from Aspose "[Why not Open XML SDK](https://docs.aspose.com/display/wordsnet/Why+not+Open+XML+SDK)".

Answer (score 3):

Our team is using [Docentric Toolkit Professional Edition](http://www.docentric.com/). One of the most important reasons for our decision was also it's relatively affordable price for teams of up to 5 developers.

The toolkit works nice with MS Office 2007/2010/2013. In our scenario, reports are produced centrally on the server, using our custom developed reporting engine, which uses Docentric api calls. Because Docentric uses OpenXML, no Word installation is needed on the server.

We have several hundreds different templates, which are ordinary Word documents, enhanced with placeholders which Docentric recognizes and fills with data at runtime during report creation.

Other features which we are using extensively are tables (included nested ones), images, graphs, conditional content and Header/Footer dynamic content.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's suited for your purpose but you might want to have a look at the b2xtranslator project on SourceForge:

> http://b2xtranslator.sourceforge.net/

Comment: I've [ported `b2xtranslator` to .NET Core 2](https://github.com/EvolutionJobs/b2xtranslator)

Answer (score 1):

If Java is an option (or a preference), you could try [docx4j](http://dev.plutext.org)

Answer (score 1):

[TX Text Control](http://textcontrol.com) has an express version, but it doesn't have all the features the full version has. The express is free, and I've used it, and if your sole purpose is to create a word processor, it will not provide all of the features. Like Aspose.Words, buying the full version is REALLY expensive ($2,398.00!), and in my opinion, a ripoff.
The pros and cons are evaluating the free version
Cons:

- No spell check in the free version
- Cannot read .docx or .doc in the free version
- No headers, footers, or dragable textboxes (like there are in Word) in the free version

Pros:

- Free
- Page breaks
- Basic Document editing features

Our company used it for a bit, but got sick of the lack of features, and ended up just ditching it.