# How to programatically produce pdfs from office (word) files from c# for free

Tags: c#, pdf, ms-office, rendering

I am currently trying to make a document rendering program in C#. One of my requirements is to be able to render word documents to pdf. However, I don't want to use automation as this is slow and from what I have read online can have issues on servers.

I've been trawling the internet and stack for a few days now and have so far not found a free, no compromise solution and I am wondering if anyone else knows of a way to do so?

If there is no good free way what would be required for me to go out there an make my own word renderer?

I have looked at solutions like Free Spire.Doc and Aspose.Words these, however, have limitations that are beyond what I can tolerate such as paragraph limits and watermarks.

Thank you.

Comment: there is a free way to do this in  regards to using a `Free .DLL / Assembly` download the `ITextSharp` library.. I convert Excel, Word , and ng-Grids, currently into PDF's but you will have to write your own methods that are specific to what your needs are.. also the site has tons of examples to get you started..

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look into it.

Comment: ITextSharp does not read OpenXML formats (e.g. XLSX and DOCX) so it cannot do this out of the box. I use [GemBox.Document](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document) for this, but its Free mode also has the paragraph count limit (similar to the ones you mentioned). The only free way that I know of would be to use any two free libraries, one for reading DOCX and one for writing PDF and then you would write the mapping from one format into another yourself. However, I should point out that this is rather complicated and time-consuming task.

Answer (score 0):

Aspose.Word and Word.Intrupt and docentric are the best.our team already used WordIntrupt and for better performance now we are using aspose .our reports include images ,toc, tof, tot, paragraphs and tables and more component .and aspose has no limitation to create reports.
you also can see this post to better decide 
[Aspose.Word alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435323/aspose-word-alternatives)